# What is the linker for mqtt and boost in visual studio?

Tags: vcpkg

My error:

cannot find -lmqtt; no such file or directory
ld returned 1 exit status

cannot find -lboost; no such file or directory
ld returned 1 exit status

I have added  in linker >input >additional library dependencies>-lboost -lmqtt
and in c/c++ >general>additional include directory> home/pi/vcpkg/installed/arm64-linux/include
and in linker general >additional library directories>home/pi/vcpkg/installed/arm64-linux/debug/lib
(I am building project on raspberrypi)

Comment: The paths should start with `/home`, not `home`. Have you checked if you have a libmqtt.a or libmqtt.so in `home/pi/vcpkg/installed/arm64-linux/debug/lib`?

Comment: i have added /home  and the library is libpaho-mqtt3a,libpaho-mqtt3as,libpaho-mqtt3cs,libpaho-mqtt3c,libpaho-mqttpp3. I have added the same path home/pi/vcpkg/installed/arm64-linux/debug/lib

Comment: If there is no `libmqtt.a` or `libmqtt.so` in the lib folder, the flag `-lmqtt` will not work. You might try `-lpaho-mqtt3a` or something similar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.